# Spark: Write Spark Data Frame with Partition. When to use it and when should be avoid it

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, partitioning

Having the following code:

```
sdf.write.partitionBy("day_of_insertion").format("delta").mode("append").save(path)
```

The partitioning is done through a column, but depending on the cardinality of that column I suppose it could be more or less interesting or totally null.

I understand that if we were to use a "user_id" as a partition column it would not make any sense and could even be detrimental as there are as many user_ids as rows.

From what percentage of the dataframe would it be interesting to make a partition?
i.e.

if I have a dataset with 10.000 rows and 1000 different <attribute_of_partition>(so 10%). In our case the `<attribute_of_partition> = "day_of_insertion"`

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on your data and use cases. A possible use case to partition the data by ‘day_of_insertion’ could be:

Supposed the you have data landing and ingested over a long period of time, and after weeks have gone by you want to drop or delete oldest data by date, having your data partitioned by `day_of_insertion` would make dropping the old data much more efficient without having the rewrite certain parts of data.